# How to Cap a Collection based on Size - MOngodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Im new to MongoDB. Im exploring options on Capped Collection.
I created a capped collection with Size :10 i assume its in Byte.

And i inserted a document of size 52 .(referring from the db.collection.stats() size option)

Shouldn't this document be rejected since its size is greater than 10b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation for MongoDB 2.6 says](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), "If the size field is less than or equal to 4096, then the collection will have a cap of 4096 bytes. Otherwise, MongoDB will raise the provided size to make it an integer multiple of 256." You can see the size MongoDB actually chose by querying system.namespaces:

```
> // Create collection of size 10.
> db.createCollection('my_collection', {capped: true, size: 10})
{ "ok" : 1 }
> // MongoDB actually sets the size to 4096.
> db.system.namespaces.findOne({name: 'test.my_collection'}).options
{ "capped" : true, "size" : 4096 }
```